# Fill inputs with urls images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal that displays various images.

I also have a form with 5 text type inputs. How do I get when clicking on an image to fill the url correct in active input?

all image tags are as follows:

```
<img data-dismiss="modal" class="img-responsive" src="nameImage.png"/>
```

Currently I can only fill a single input

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $('#url_image').val($(this).attr('src'));
})
```

Form:

```
<form method="post">
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Show images</button>
    <input type="text" id="url_image" name="url_image" value="">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I can't see any image tags in your code

Comment: You could assign them statically by using a class and `.url_image` instead of `#url_image`. Do you want them to be linked in order only? If not you may want to assign a data attribute to the inputs and the images and get the matching input for the images attribute.

Comment: _to fill the url correct in active input..._ What do you exactly mean by "active input"? input having focus? But it will be lost once you click an image.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I updated my question, please see

Comment: _"How do I get when clicking on an image to fill the url correct in active input?"_ Current `js` achieves this. _"Currently I can only fill a single input"_ This appears to be expected result described ? Is requirement to fill all `input` elements with `img` `src` ? Note also `button` within `form` element could submit `form` when clicked ?

Comment: @Hindmost yes, when the input having focus

Comment: Only **one** element on web page can have focus **at the same time**. When user click on any element (image), previously focused element (input) loses focus.

Comment: I do not know how to avoid creating 5 modal buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `focus` event to store last `input` element focused on, use this variable to update `input` `value`.

Note, `button` element clicked within `form` element could cause `form` to submit

```js
var focused = null;

$("input").on("focus", function() {
  focused = $(this);
})

$("img").click(function() {
  if (focused.length)
  focused.val($(this).attr("src"));
})
```

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="url_image" name="url_image" value="">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Show images</button>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature" />
```

Comment: please see: [Input does not properly fill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902174/input-does-not-properly-fill)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in this way.

JS :

```
$(".common_class").on('focus', function() {

     $(".common_class").removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
})

$('img').click(function() {
     $('.common_class.active').val($(this).attr('src'));
})
```

HTML :

```
<form method="post">
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Show images</button>
        <input type="text" class="common_class" name="url_image" value="">
        <input type="text" class="common_class">
        <input type="text" class="common_class">
        <input type="text" class="common_class">
        <input type="text" class="common_class">
        <input type="submit">
        <img data-dismiss="modal" class="img-responsive" src="nameImage.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I marked the response of @guest271314 because it is simpler and use native properties